# Two different ways to express List in Prolog

Tags: prolog

what's the difference between these two clauses:

```
L=[X,H|Y].

append(X,[H|Y],L).
```

It's one clause in my code, first one does not work, second one works, just don't know the difference.

Comment: Check your syntax. Did you mean, `append(X, [H|Y], L).`? It's totally different than what you show which, in SWI Prolog, will a create a list structure with the term `(H|Y)` as a tail. I'm pretty sure that's not what you want or meant. And `append(X, [H|T], L)` assumes that `X` is a list.

Comment: Yes, I made syntax error above. I meant [H|Y]. So in L=[X,[H|Y]], can X be a list?

Comment: The first form, `L = [X,H|Y]` unifies the variable `L` with the list `[X,H|Y]`, and `[X,H|Y]` is a list whose first two elements are `X` and `H` and has tail `Y`. `append(X, H|Y, L)` appends the list `X` to the term `(H|Y)` yielding a list term `L`. For `append`, `X` is assumed to be a list.

Comment: Could you please edit your question so it's clear what all the changes/fixes are?

Comment: If you had `append([X], [H|Y], L)`, then they would have the same effect.

Comment: You are comparing two **goals**, not clauses.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `[X,H|Y]` denotes a list whose first term is the value of X, whose second term is the value of H, and whose tail is the value of Y.  If X = 1, H = 2, and Y = [3,4,5], its value will be [1,2,3,4,5].  If X = [1,2,3], H = [4,5,6], and Y = [7,8,9], its value will be [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], 7, 8, 9].  The expression `L=[X,H|Y]` binds the value of the list to L.

The predicate `append(X,[H|Y],L)`, on the other hand, appends the list whose first term is H and whose tail is Y to the list X, and binds the result to L.  If X = 1, H = 2, and Y = [3,4,5], the result will be an error, since X is not a list.  If X = [1,2,3], H = [4,5,6], and Y = [7,8,9], the result will be to bind L to the value [1,2,3, [4,5,6], 7, 8, 9].